# Can you explain what each line of the C++ function is doing? It sends keystrokes but I am confused by how

Tags: c++, winapi, sendkeys, sendinput, keystrokes

I was making a program to send keystrokes to another window and I got it all working, but I had to go online and find a function to do the keystroke portion itself. It works but I have no idea what it is actually doing. Can someone comment each line of this function explaining what it's doing?

```
void GenerateKey(int vk, BOOL bExtended) {

    KEYBDINPUT  kb = {0};
    INPUT       Input = {0};

    /* Generate a "key down" */
    if (bExtended) { kb.dwFlags  = KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY; }
    kb.wVk  = vk;
    Input.type  = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    Input.ki  = kb;
    SendInput(1, &Input, sizeof(Input));

    /* Generate a "key up" */
    ZeroMemory(&kb, sizeof(KEYBDINPUT));
    ZeroMemory(&Input, sizeof(INPUT));
    kb.dwFlags  =  KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
    if (bExtended) { kb.dwFlags |= KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY; }
    kb.wVk = vk;
    Input.type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    Input.ki = kb;
    SendInput(1, &Input, sizeof(Input));

    return;
}
```

Here's an example of a call to it:

```
GenerateKey('C', FALSE);    // Sends keystroke 'c'
```

This sends the keystroke 'c'.

This function only works with capital letters and seems to only work with specific hex codes. For example, to send a carriage return (enter key), here is the call:

```
GenerateKey(0x0D, FALSE);   // Sends carriage return
```

However, if I try sending a question mark (hex 0x3F) with either of these calls, nothing happens:

```
GenerateKey(0x3F, FALSE);  // Nothing happens
GenerateKey('?', FALSE);   // Nothing happens
```

Can anyone see why those wouldn't work?

Also, can someone explain what the second argument, BOOL bExtended, is for? Changing between TRUE and FALSE seems to make no difference in the keystrokes it sends.

Comment: Your question is WinAPI specific and should be tagged as such. C++ standard don't know about keystrokes.

Comment: There is no question mark key on the keyboard.  You'd want to send SHIFT+`/` (on a US QWERTY keyboard layout, YMMV).

Answer (score 4):

Your `GenerateKey` function makes internal use of the **`SendInput` function** from the Win32 API, which synthesizes keyboard input.

You can find all of the information you need to understand how that function works and how to call it by reading the [MSDN documentation for that function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310.aspx).

The `vk` parameter is a **virtual key code**, listed [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375731.aspx).

If the `bExtended` parameter is `TRUE`, then the `KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY` flag is set, which according to [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646271.aspx) means that "the scan code was preceded by a prefix byte that has the value 0xE0 (224)".

Comment: Great, thanks! The virtual key codes were the main things holding me up but I understand them now.

Comment: @user1125316: Sorry, I just noticed my link to the list of virtual key codes was broken. I fixed it now.